# Formulating testable hypotheses

Tags: biostatistics, epidemiology

This isn't a stats question but I hope this is the most appropriate community for it. I'm writing a research proposal for an Epidemiology study. I have been told that none of my hypotheses are testable and I cannot figure out what is lacking. Please see below and note that the reviewers did have access to methodological details regarding my planned statistical analyses.

---

**Aim 1: To identify individual-level predictors and trends of [*bacterial species*] AMR among men with [STD] in [US city].**

Hypothesis 1a:  Among men with [STD] in [US city], infection with [mutated form of STD] is associated with covariate1, covariate2, covariate3, covariate4, and covariate5.

**Aim 2: To compare non-spatial and spatial multilevel modelling approaches to investigating geographical variations of [mutated form of STD] among men with [STD] in [US city].**

Hypothesis 2a: [One kind of] multilevel modelling will better predict [mutated form of STD] among [US city] men with [STD] compared to [a different kind of] multilevel modelling.

Hypothesis 2b: In [US city], [mutated form of STD] among men with [STD] is associated with covariate6, increases with greater covariate7, and is clustered in covariate8.

Hypothesis 2c: Among men with [STD] in [US city], infection with [mutated form of STD] is associated with a combination of individual- and area-level predictors.

**Aim 3: To describe [mutated form of STD] trends throughout the Americas.**

Hypothesis 3a: In the American Region, [mutated form of STD] is associated with covariate6, increases with greater covariate7, and is clustered in covariate8.

Comment: Can you provide the reviewer's criticisms? These seem mostly do-able to me, although some diverge from the prototypical biomedical study. In 2a, is 1 of the modeling types nested w/i the other? What exactly do you mean by "[mutated... associated w/..."? Eg, are you comparing the mutated form to the default form, or is the presence / absence of the mutated form the response variable? If so, how are you getting your sample? What are the inclusion / exclusion criteria?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reviewer commented: "The one suggestion that I have is that you rewrite your hypothesis so that they are testable. The way they are right now, they are not testable." He/she further commented in the document itself: "Please make sure that this is how a hypothesis is written." Next, he/she stated that I should specify examples of individual and area level predictors mentioned in 2c. There were no further comments from said reviewer.

Comment: In 2a, I suppose that you could consider one of them nested within the other. I'm interested in comparing spatial vs. non-spatial multilevel modelling.

The presence/absence of the mutated form is the response variable.

For Aims 1 and 2, the sample will come from health department sentinel surveillance data.

Comment: I will include all individuals from the surveillance data set in my analysis. These individuals are males with the STD who presented themselves to local health clinics. Demographic and clinical data were collected and specimens were obtained for laboratory analysis to identify mutant variants of the STD. This would basically be a Ca/Co design where the cases would be men with the STD who have the mutant variant and the controls would be men with the STD who don't have the mutant variant.

Comment: The response variable (presence/absence of mutated form) for Aim 3 will come from national surveillance data. Independent variables will be derived from other national datasets.

Comment: Your stated hypotheses seem to be alternative hypotheses, not null hypotheses. Maybe the reviewer wants you to state the null hypotheses which would be tested to "prove" the alternatives. There are major problems with null hypothesis significance testing. Maybe the reviewer expects you to indicate the hypothesized magnitude of associations/differences and demonstrate that you will be able to detect/estimate them.

Answer (score 1):

My closest guess is that your reviewer wants things laid out in a much more formalized way than you have currently presented them, as @user20637 has suggested. Because, to be blunt, all of these are perfectly testable.

So, for example, something like this for 1a:

"The null hypothesis is that the regression coefficients for covariates 1,2,3,4, and 5 are equal to 0 when conditioned on each other, and any other covariates in the model."